# In need of a simple book on English phonology - recommendations?

Tags: phonology, reference-request, american-english

SPE of Chomsky and Halle entails far more than I can handle.

Comment: What do you mean by "English phonology"? English segment allophony? Dialectology? McMahon's book? Giegerich? Ogden "Introduction to English Phonetics". Daniel Kahn's dissertation?

Comment: Mainly phonotactics

Comment: There isn't one, at least not a linguistic book. There might be some orthography-based letter co-occurrence study in the computational literature.

Answer (score 1):

[Roach (2009: 64)](https://books.google.com/books?id=dDVR_zh5wkMC&pg=PA62) recommends Cruttenden's *Gimson's Pronunciation of English* (2008; [last edn. 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=kXzMAgAAQBAJ)) and Kreidler's [*The Pronunciation of English: A Course Book* (2008)](https://books.google.com/books?id=i8jKGdOtqQsC) for in-depth descriptions of English phonotactics.

Comment: Thanks, I've got my hands on them already.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about this function; I'll do it :)